# Using a PV in an OpenShift 3 cron job

Tags: cron, openshift, persistent-volumes

I have been able to successfully create a cron job for my OpenShift 3 project. The project is a lift and shift from an existing Linux web server. Part of the existing application requires several cron tasks to run. The one I am looking at the moment is a daily update to the applications database. As part of the execution of the cron job I want to write to a log file. There is already a PV/PVC defined for the main application and I was intending to use that hold the logs for my cron job but it seems the cron job is not being provided access to the PV.

I am using the following **inProgress.yml** for the definition of the cron job

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: in-progress
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"       
  concurrencyPolicy: "Replace"  
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 200  
  suspend: false                
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3 
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1     
  jobTemplate:                  
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:               
            parent: "cronjobInProgress"
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: in-progress
            image: <image name>
            command: ["php",  "inProgress.php"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure 
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data-pv
              name: log-vol
      volumes:
        - name: log-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: data-pv
```

I am using the following command to create the cron job

```
oc create -f inProgress.yml
```

> PHP Warning:  fopen(/data-pv/logs/2022-04-27-app.log): failed to open
> stream: No such file or directory in
> /opt/app-root/src/errorHandler.php on line 75 WARNING: [2] mkdir():
> Permission denied, line 80 in file
> /opt/app-root/src/errorLogger.php
>  WARNING: [2]
> fopen(/data-pv/logs/2022-04-27-inprogress.log): failed to open stream:
> No such file or directory, line 60 in file
> /opt/app-root/src/errorLogger.php

Looking at the yml for pod that is executed, there is no mention of **data-pv** - it appears as though secret **volumeMount**, which has been added by **OpenShift**, is removing any further **volumeMounts**.

```
 apiVersion: v1 kind: Pod metadata:   annotations:
     openshift.io/scc: restricted   creationTimestamp: '2022-04-27T13:25:04Z'   generateName: in-progress-1651065900- ...
 
       volumeMounts:
         - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
           name: default-token-n9jsw
           readOnly: true ...   volumes:
     - name: default-token-n9jsw
       secret:
         defaultMode: 420
         secretName: default-token-n9jsw
```

How can I access the PV from within the cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest is incorrect. The `volumes` block needs to be part of the `spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec`, that is, it needs to be indented at the same level as `spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers`. In its current position it is invisible to OpenShift. See e.g. [this pod example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#aws-ebs-configuration-example).

Similarly, `volumeMounts` and `restartPolicy` are arguments to the `container` block, and need to be indented accordingly.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: in-progress
spec:
  schedule: '*/5 * * * *'
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 200
  suspend: false
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            parent: cronjobInProgress
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: in-progress
              image: <image name>
              command:
                - php
                - inProgress.php
              restartPolicy: OnFailure
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /data-pv
                  name: log-vol
          volumes:
            - name: log-vol
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: data-pv
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the informative response larsks.

OpenShift displayed the following when I copied your manifest suggestions

> $ oc create -f InProgress.yml The CronJob "in-progress" is invalid:
> spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value:
> "Always": supported values: "OnFailure", " Never"

As your answer was very helpful I was able to resolve this problem by moving **restartPolicy: OnFailure** so the final manifest is below.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: in-progress
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"       
  concurrencyPolicy: "Replace"  
  startingDeadlineSeconds: 200  
  suspend: false                
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3 
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1     
  jobTemplate:                  
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:               
            parent: "cronjobInProgress"
        spec:
          restartPolicy: OnFailure 
          containers:
          - name: in-progress
            image: <image name>
            command: ["php",  "updateToInProgress.php"]
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /data-pv
                name: log-vol
          volumes:
            - name: log-vol
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: data-pv
```